# Concatenate variables of types HEX and String on Arduino

Tags: arduino, hex, concatenation, nfc

On my Arduino Uno, I would like to concatenate a value of type HEX, to which I added 0: example 35 --> "000035", so it's a HEX.

In my code I would like to store this value in a string, but I can not do it. I do not understand what type I have and how to declare it.
Here is the code:

```
 char value_1;
 char value_2;

if (nfc.ntag2xx_read (page_1, data)) {value_1 = string(print_hex_short (data, 4));}
if (nfc.ntag2xx_read (page_2, data)) {value_2 = string(print_hex_short (data, 4));}
  String image = String ("https: //example_" + value_1 + "-" + value_2 + ".png");
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: try using a [String constructor](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors)

Comment: There is no variable type hex.  Hexadecimal is a way that the programmer can write a number, but to the computer it is just a number and it will be represented in binary no matter how the programmer wrote it.  Can you explain what you actually have or post a complete example that illustrates it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put an hexadecimal value inside a String object, you can do:

```
String s = "A string: 0x";
uint32_t h = 0xDECAFBAD;
s = s + String(h, HEX);
```

`s` is now:

> A string: 0xDECAFBAD

[Yes, DECAFBAD is a valid hexadecimal, 3,737,844,653 in decimal).